# Animate the height of UILabel to 0

Tags: ios, animation, size, height, uilabel

I've got a UILabel and what I want to do is to smoothly change it's height to 0.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.label1.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    self.label1.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

The problem is that the animation is jamming does some wierd things. I guess that the label is trying to resize and reposition it's text and that is why it does not work. I've tried like every possible combination of properties on the label but without success.

Comment: What effect do you want/are you expecting for the text while its height changes?

Comment: is it the height or the position you wish to animate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could enclose your `UILabel` into another `UIView`, set the enclosing `UIView` `autoresizesSubviews`' property to `NO` and `clipToBounds` to `YES`, and then animate the height of the enclosing `UIView`...

Answer (score 3):

Try with a transform. I dug this code out for you:

```
    //[self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0) forView:self.label];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^{ 
                     //Scale the height to close to zero
                     //0.00001, because 0.0 behaves strange
                     self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.00001);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.label.hidden = YES;
                 }];
```

This will shrink it into the middle. If you want it to shrink to the top or bottom, you will need to set an anchor point. I also have some code for this too:

```
- (void) setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view {
CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);

CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

position.x -= oldPoint.x;
position.x += newPoint.x;

position.y -= oldPoint.y;
position.y += newPoint.y;

view.layer.position = position;
view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```